# How to handle exception in spring with @ControllerAdvice even though we are handling exception in catch block

Tags: java, spring

Not able to use @ControllerAdvice and  @AfterThrowing when method surrounded by try and catch block.

I can explain step by step

**Step 1:** In my spring application all handlers(methods) are handle exception  by try and catch block.

**Step 2:** So requirement i need to trigger a email when the exception occurs in all handlers methods. But my application having 100's of methods. So try with @ControllerAdvice  to handle the exceptions by using @ExceptionHandler annotation. I know that it wont work because we already handling our exception in catch block. So it cant look at @ControllerAdvice.

**Step 3:** I try with Aop  @AfterThrowing advice also. It is not working. So i cant able to remove all catch blocks in entire application code. It is very difficultly to do that.

But my question is that 
    Is there any way in spring to handle the exception even we are handling it.
   We returning back status code like 400 . In Spring they any Advice to identify status code.
    Because are retiring ResponseEntity Status back as response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getDetails(@RequestBody Details details, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = null;
    try {
        /// Some code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while DetailsController: " + e.getMessage());
        response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        /*
         * int status=response.getStatusCodeValue();
         * scheduledMailTrigerService.sendErrorLogInfo(request,e,status);
         */
    }
    return response;
}

  @ControllerAdvice
  public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
public String handleAnyException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Done");
    return "Done";
}
```

}

Comment: @ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
 @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
 public String handleAnyException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
  System.out.println("Done");
  return "Done";
 }

}

Comment: You may try to impement [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) `postHandle` method and check the httpResponse with status code.

Comment: Thanks, but that handler cant know what type of exception it is ??               public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
   Object object, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
  
   int status=response.getStatus();
  //scheduledMailTrigerService.sendErrorLogInfo(request,e,status);*/
  System.out.println("postHandle Interceptor is called");
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `@Around` advice to capture the result of the method execution... my suggestion is that you remove the try catch from all your endpoints, just write a try catch wrapping the **ProceedingJoinPoint** `proceed()` execution. This way you can return a **ResponseEntity 400** when an exception occurs, alongside execututing email sending logic.

Comment: Apart from Aop and @controller advice any other approach is there ??? (only when catch block is there)